# What is the difference between tags and filters?

Tags: support, tags, filtering

Here is a little story on how I have been using Stack Overflow for about one year.

I first created one account on stackoverflow.com. Posted some questions, bla bla, then started to add tags to filter the "noise" (don't get me wrong : "stackoverflow (community+content) is amazing").

Then, I discovered new verticals and repeated the same pattern. Created one account, added tags...

This morning, I discovered "filters" and thought "All the content (without the noise) from the different verticals on one single page ? It sounds amazing".

But I don't understand the difference between "tags" and "filters" in that context. Do these two features have an influence on each other ? If so, how ?

Went to the FAQ, did some research but didn't find anything interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Filters(formerly tagsets) comprised of collections of tags ("tagsets") - questions based the tagsets you had selected would be visible on Stack Exchange, as well as emailed to you. Tagsets were later renamed to Filters to make it clear what tagsets actually perform on [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) as mentioned in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/)

> Tag sets are actually an incredibly powerful feature, but the UI for it … uh, not so good.
>
> We rolled up our sleeves and built an all new, much friendlier interface. We also renamed it to something that’s hopefully a bit clearer: filters.
>
> Filters (née Tag Sets) are a perfect way to follow activity on tags across the whole Stack Exchange network

Comment: Thanks for pointing the article. It seems I am not the only one to be unsatisfied/confused with the current filtering system.